# Java: Solving unchecked call

Tags: java, android

I'm having an issue with unchecked calls even though I already introduced the type parameter to my method.
I don't want to suppress the warnings because I'm pretty sure there's a way to prevent that somehow.

#### My main class (which is giving me the warning)

```
HttpUtil.fetch(
        url,
        headers,
        HttpRequest.Method.POST,
        new HttpRequest.Form.Builder(HttpRequest.Form.Encoding.URL_ENCODED)
                .set("password", iLoginPass.getText().toString())
                .set("login", iLoginUser.getText().toString())
                .build()
)
.then(HttpResponse::getBody)
.then((Promise.Resolver<Void, Document>) value -> {
    final Elements elems = value.body().getElementsByTag("table");
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, elems.text(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return null;
});
```

#### My Promise class

```
// T: input, U: progress (unused but just in case), V: output (resolved value)
public class Promise<T, U, V> {
    // RV: new return value (aka. resolved value)
    public <RV> Promise then(final Resolver<RV, V> nextResolver){
        return new Promise<V, U, RV>(nextResolver, this.rejector, resolvedValue);
    }
}
```

Also ignore the `HttpUtil.fetch` function because it returns a Promise object with parameter types `<String, Void, HttpResponse>`. The body should return another object from Document class which shouldn't be a problem because if I did `.<Document>then(...)` it tells me 'the parameterized type is redundant' and wanted me to infer the type. Also, the important thing to note here is the warning pop out only if I did with two or more `.then(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind. I know how to fix this.

The `.then(...)` function's return type is a raw `Promise`. It needs the generics parameter

```
public class Promise<T, U, V> {
    public <RV> Promise<V, U, RV> then(final Resolver<RV, V> nextResolver){
        return new Promise<V, U, RV>(nextResolver, this.rejector, resolvedValue);
    }
}
```

With that the warning went away